# Is it possible to create numeric range slicer and filter data in matrix in Power BI Desktop?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop

I have matrix with two measures: `Total Premium` and `Binds Total`
.............................................................

[image]

Is it possible to create range slicer (something like the one below), that would filter data in a matrix based on amount of premium?

[image]

The data in a query looks like this:

[image]

So the SUM of `Premum` per each `ControlNo` should correspond to Range Slicer.

For example `ControlNo` 10 should be in range between `10,000 and 20,000`. Because 3,000 + 9,000 = $12,000

And `ControlNo` 20 should be in a range between `20,000 and 30,000`
Because 15,000 + 7,000 = $22,000

.PBIX file can be accessed here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a3l6e51r39t3kd1/GrossBudgetTest.pbix?dl=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marco's answer looks good, but you can also achieve the grouping with a calculated column instead of defining a new table and use that column as a slicer:

```
Range = 
VAR Premium =
    CALCULATE(SUM(fact_Premium[Premium]),
        ALLEXCEPT(fact_Premium, fact_Premium[ControlNo])
    )
RETURN
    SWITCH(TRUE(),
        Premium <= 10000, "From 0 to 10,000",
        Premium <= 20000, "From 10,000 to 20,000",
        Premium <= 30000, "From 20,000 to 30,000",
        Premium <= 40000, "From 30,000 to 40,000",
        Premium >  40000, "More than 40,000"
    )
```

The downside of this is that it's not a measure and may not interact with your slicers the way you want since calculated columns are unaffected by slicers.

---

Note Power BI does have some [built-in binning capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-grouping-and-binning).

For example, you could right-click on the `Premium` column and select Group and choose how you want to bin your data.

[image: Binning]

That's not going to work for you in this case since you want to bin at an aggregated level.

Comment: Another current issue with grouping is that you can only control the order of the groups by using labels that sort alphanumerically. e.g. "1. $50k to $100k", "2. $500k to $1M"

Answer (score 3):

First create a table 'Ranges'. You can import it or use Enter Data on the Home-tab. It should look like this:

[image]

Then create these three maesures:

`MinThreshold = MIN('Ranges'[Min])`

`MaxThreshold = MAX('Ranges'[Max])`

```
Total Premium per ControlNo in Range =
VAR selectedControlNo =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'fact_Premium'[ControlNo] )
RETURN
    IF (
        CALCULATE ( [Total Premium], 'fact_Premium'[ControlNo] = selectedControlNo )
            >= [MinThreshold]
            && CALCULATE ( [Total Premium], 'fact_Premium'[ControlNo] = selectedControlNo )
                < [MaxThreshold],
        [Total Premium],
        BLANK ()
    )
```

You cannot use the SELECTEDVALUE function directly in [Filter1] of the CALCULATE function. That's why you have to use the VAR RETURN or the CALCULATE(expression,FILTER()) construct in this maesure.

Now you can create the following matrix & slicer. Put 'Ranges'[Ranges] in the slicer. Put 'fact_Premium'[ControlNo] on Rows and [Total Premium per ControlNo in Range] on Values in the Matrix.

[image]